# How to handle authorization in the view layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, view, acl

Authorize attribute are good to do some access control base on Action but suppose that I have some UI element in the layout that should note be output unless the user is authorize.

I could possibly set some boolean in the ViewBag but that is not the good solution I guess.

Somewhere in the Layout.cshtml:

```
@if (ViewBag.IsAuthorized)
{
     <li>@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Admin")</li>
}
```

Let me know if there is a better solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`WebPageRenderingBase.User`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagerenderingbase.user%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) object; assuming you've earlier set the user into the HttpContext, or on the Controller (which you really should be).  Since you're using the `Authorize` attribute I'm thinking there must be a `User` - so hopefully the following should work.

This `User` can be accessed in Razor very easily:

```
@User.Identity.Name
```

Would output the current user's name.  So an `if` block that runs only if the user is authenticated would be:

```
@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
   Hello
}
```

Outputs `"Hello"` if the user is authenticated.

Thanks to James below for reminding me that you can check `IsAuthenticated` off the `User` object - I couldn't find it initially - but then remembered it's on the `Identity`!

Comment: Which details are you missing?

Comment: @AndrasZoltan deleted my comment as I see you updated anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `helper method` and call that from the layout.

```
@Helper.IsAuthorize()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call a function that verifies if the user is authenticated:

**Helper:**

```
public bool checkUser(string user)
{
//User is allowed?
return true/false;
}
```

**Layout:**

```
@if (checkUser(User.Identity.Name)
{
     <li>@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Admin")</li>
}
```